# how to repeat a small background image througout the page?

Tags: html, css, repeat

I want to set page background image my css code is-

```
background:url(images/body_bg.jpg) repeat-x top;
```

but the image size is not as large as web page thats a thin strip only and gradient color too.so how can i repeat the image so that it will occupy whole background?As I said it is gradient so I can't hardcore the background color.

Comment: if it's a gradient then repeat-y will only repeat the gradient, not stretch it as you probably want

Comment: @may if i would repeat y then how it'll occupy the whole page?

Comment: repeat x and y of course nectar, but my answer was a different approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[See demo here.](http://jsbin.com/owili3/2)

```
background:url(images/body_bg.jpg) repeat left top;
```

More Info:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could use this `background: #000000 url(images/body_bg.jpg) repeat-x top;` 
And replace `#000000` with the color, which ends your gradient.